# Finding related functional dependencies from Amstrong's axioms

Tags: dependencies

Let be

```
F = { AB → C,
       B → D,
      CD → E,
      CE → GH,
       G → A }
```

some functional dependencies.

Do we have, thanks to Amstrong's axioms or its corollaries `AB → G`?

## My attempt

I don't think so because

```
AB → C
CE → GH
```

Then from the **pseudo-transitivity** rule:

> {X → Y, WY → Z}⊨XW → Z

Then

```
ABE → GH
```

And tht's all. We can't get rid of H.

Answer (score 1):

This is rather easy.

```
AB → C
B → D

therefore:

AB → C
AB → D

and:

AB → CD
```

Next:

```
AB → CD
CD → E

therefore:

AB → E

with: AB → C
we get:

AB → CE
```

And finally:

```
CE → GH

thus:

CE → G

and with the (previous): AB → CE

AB → G
```